# H.264 videos fail in Firefox or Chromium on Fedora 30

Tags: fedora, video, browser, codec

https://www.youtube.com/html5 reports my browsers (Firefox 66.0.5-1.fc30 and Chromium 73.0.3683.86-2.fc30) on my [Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-970A-UD3-rev-10-11#ov) with a [Radeon RX-580](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-580) GPU don't support H.264. I've tried installing `gstreamer1-plugin-openh264.x86_64`, `mozilla-openh264.x86_64`, and `openh264.x86_64`, from `fedora-cisco-openh264` but that didn't help.

What's my next step?

Comment: @K7AAY This isn't about stability (Fedora is quite stable, and not really all that bleeding edge) but about the requirement for non-free software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can gather, the missing package that makes YouTube HTML5 videos work in Firefox (and possibly Chrome) is `ffmpeg`. This you can find in [negativo17's fedora-multimedia repo](https://negativo17.org/multimedia/), or in rpmfusion-free (but don't install both repos as they conflict).

From some notes made by negativo17, it appears that he has only built hardware H.264 acceleration for NVIDIA GPUs. I'm not sure if that means it won't work with AMD GPUs or if it will work anyway but without acceleration. You might end up thinking about buying a different GPU.

[image: YouTube HTML5 on Fedora]

Comment: ffmpeg-libs from rpmfusion did the trick! thank you

Comment: That should do you nicely, then. I have an NVIDIA GPU so I use negativo17's packages instead of rpmfusion.

Comment: I had to restart my system also to get the videos working